# Onclick open new window javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open new window using Javascript. My code is given below.

```js
function openMeeting()
{
  var popup = window.open("myurl", "_blank", "menubar= yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width="+screen.availWidth+",height="+screen.availHeight);
  if (popup == null)
     alert('Please change your popup settings', popup);
}
```

```html
    <li class="nav-item"> <a href="#" class="nav-link" onclick="openMeeting();"> Join meeting </a> </li>
```

New window is opening using this code, but it is not same as like that of new tab, the menus are missing. I need to show the bookmarks also.

Comment: From first sight i can tell you your code structure is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

That may not be possible 
Read this : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82522

Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="link">Link</a>
<script  type="text/javascript">
     $("a.link").on("click",function(){
         window.open('http://google.com','_blank');
     });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy this code , in code snippet/stackoverflow open popup is not allowed.

```js
function openMeeting()
{
   var popup = window.open("https://stackoverflow.com", "popUpWindow", "height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes");
    
   if (popup == null) alert('Please change your popup settings');
   
}


/*
menubar= yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width="+screen.availWidth+",height="+screen.availHeight

window.open('https://www.quackit.com/javascript/examples/sample_popup.cfm','popUpWindow','height=500,width=400,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=yes')
*/
```

```html
<li class="nav-item"> <a href="#" class="nav-link" onclick="openMeeting();"> Join meeting </a> </li>
```